# LineEdit in Pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I want to use pyqt5 to modify my docs.

Enter some information (eg, IP ..., etc.) into the interface

And then use these variables to replace the original example of the information

But the input value does not appear on the file

The file show 'None'

If set

```
 ip = self.lineEdit_ip.text()
```

The file show  ' '

This is my code

```
import sys, os  
import platform

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import ezplan_form
from ezplan_form import Ui_MainWindow

if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    ezPath = os.path.join('F:\\','plan')
else:
    ezPath = os.path.join('F','plan')

class MyForm(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('SetezPlan')
        self.SetIP()

    def SetIP(self):
        ip = str(self.lineEdit_ip.text())

        f=open(os.path.join(ezPath,'Server.txt'),'r+')  
        flist=f.readlines()  
        flist[0]= ip
        f=open(os.path.join(ezPath,'Server.txt'),'w+')  
        f.writelines(flist)
        self.pushButton_ok.clicked.connect(f.close)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myform = MyForm()
    myform.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How can I modify my code??

*Update(04/06)
@kamik423 The result like image. Not '6.6.6.6' .

[image]

Comment: Firstly (from how it looks to me) you are only calling `SetIP()` when the window opens, not when you write something. Secondly I'd only write to file once the button is pressed. Thirdly you can just delete the `f=open(os.path.join(ezPath,'Server.txt'),'w+') ` line, because the file is already opened for writing.

Comment: Thanks ! How can I do that it will save the modify when I write something in the interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `editingFinished` signal, this is executed after placing the text and pressing `Enter` or `Return`, that is, places the desired text and then press `Enter` or `Return`.

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.setWindowTitle('SetezPlan')
    self.SetIP()
    self.lineEdit_ip.editingFinished.connect(self.SetIP)

def SetIP(self, event):
    ip = str(self.lineEdit_ip.text())
    with open(os.path.join(ezPath,'Server.txt'),'r+') as f:
        flist=f.readlines()  
        flist[0]= ip
        f.writelines(flist)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Thank for your help ! It succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Solution (not tested, because I don't have the rest of the program)
`SetIP` now gets called every time a symbol is entered or deleted inside the `lineEdit`. It opens the file, writes to the first line and saves it again. The button now is unnecessary (from what I can tell)

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.setWindowTitle('SetezPlan')
    self.lineEdit_ip.textChanged.connect(self.SetIP)

def SetIP(self, event):
    ip = str(self.lineEdit_ip.text())
    with open(os.path.join(ezPath,'Server.txt'),'r+') as f:
        flist=f.readlines()  
        flist[0]= ip
        f.writelines(flist)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Thank for your help! I tried your code but failed .

Comment: I changed something, can you try again. what is your error? Does the file exist?

Comment: My problem is solved ! I use `self.lineEdit_ip.editingFinished.connect(self.SetIP)` to fix the promblem. Thank for your help!!

Comment: Yes, but that only saves after you deselect the textfield, not while you enter text.